# Including an image in a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I would like to use an image in firefox extension I am developing. Can someone tell me how to include the image. I used the following but it did not work.

```
    var divTag = content.document.createElement("img");                 
    divTag.id = "div1";
    divTag.src="chrome://ff_extension/content/image1.gif";
    divTag.setAttribute("align","center");
    divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";
    divTag.style.position="fixed";
    divTag.style.bottom="0px";
    divTag.style.height="22px";
        divTag.style.width="100%";
            content.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divTag);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use the relative path?

```
divTag.src="image1.gif";
```

I just looked at some plugins i have installed and they use the same **chrome://** syntax you used.

- Did you double check your the file path?
- Are you positive you can embed a gif? It would be ridiculous if you couldn't but it's worth double checking. All I see being used are png's.